# Executing the next line of code after subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.4, tcpdump

I am executing Tcpdump command using Popen. In my code, the popen line runs but it does not execute the next line of code following the popen line of code. Why is it happening and how can I solve this ? Thanks.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os
import time

pw ='12345678'
process = Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'tcpdump', '-i', 'wlp1s0', 'udp', 'port 8308', '-w', 'trace.pcap'], stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True,stdin=PIPE)
process.communicate(pw + '\n')[1]
print("Command ran")
time.sleep(3)
```

Here the "Command ran" is not printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.communicate` waits for process to terminate.

If you want to send input to process without waiting for termination use `process.stdin`.

```
process.stdin.write(password + "\n")
```

[tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) will not terminate with your parameters unless you send SIGINT signal.

> Tcpdump will, if not run with the -c flag, continue capturing packets until it is interrupted by a SIGINT signal (generated, for example, by typing your interrupt character, typically control-C) or a SIGTERM signal (typically generated with the kill(1) command); if run with the -c flag, it will capture packets until it is interrupted by a SIGINT or SIGTERM signal or the specified number of packets have been processed.

You can include -c flag in your parameters.

Comment: I do not want to terminate tcpdump here. I want my code to run tcpdump as subprocess and continue running the rest of the code. Since process.communicate waits for the process to terminate, how can I pass my password without using process.communicate ?

Comment: Try with `process.stdin.write("\n" + password+"\n")` or without "\n". `process.stdin` is your pipe for input to subproccess. You might need to close it `process.stdin.close()`.  Password prompt should be in output anyway.

Comment: Try running command in new shell to see expected input and output.

Comment: process.stdin.write(password + "\n") worked. I was missing '-S' for the sudo in Popen. I am able to write the output to the file. If I need to print the output to stdout as well as write to the file, how can I do it ?

Comment: You could accept answer since original question is answered. Output from you get from `process.stdout` eg `text = process.stdout.readline()` you can print to stdout `print(text)` and file `print(text, file=myfile)`.